# ANTLR4 RegEx lexer modes

Tags: regex, antlr4

I am working on a Regx parser for RegEx inside XSD.
My previous problem was descrived here: [ANTLR4 parsing RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177478/antlr4-parsing-regex)

I have split the Lexer and Parser since than.
Now I have a problem parsing parantheses inside brackets. They should be treated as characters inside the brackets and as grouping tokens outside.
This is my lexer grammar:

```
lexer grammar RegExLexer;

Char    : ALPHA ;
Int     : DIGIT ;

LBrack  : '[' ;//-> pushMode(modeRange) ;
RBrack  : ']' ;//-> popMode ;
LBrace  : '(' ;
RBrace  : ')' ;
Semi    : ';' ;
Comma   : ',' ;
Asterisk: '*' ;
Plus    : '+' ;
Dot     : '.' ;
Dash    : '-' ;
Question: '?' ;
LCBrace : '{' ;
RCBrace : '}' ;
Pipe    : '|' ;
Esc     : '\\' ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
fragment ALPHA : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

And here is the example:

```
[0-9a-z()]+
```

I feel like i should use modes on brackets to change the behaviour of ALPHA fragment. If I copy the fragment, I get an error saying I can't have the declaration twice.
I have read the reference about this and I still don't get what i should do.

How do I implement the modes?

Comment: What about `CharSet : '[''^'?']'?'-'?([^]\\-]'-'[^]\\-]|[^]\\-]|ESCAPE_SEQUENCE)*'-'?']'`

Comment: I just don't know what you meant and houw to use this.

Comment: it's a token for antlr that is a character class.

Comment: @programmerjake I too have no idea what you're talking about :)

Comment: @Bart for instance, it would match and return as a token `[^-a-zA-Z_]`

Comment: @programmerjake we're talking about regexes in ANTLR. My guess is that you've never heard of it, right?

Comment: @BartKiers no, I was writing a ANTLR lexer token definition that matches a character set specifier. Like [a-zA-Z0-9] or [^34].

Comment: I can see what you are trying to do, but that is not valid ANTLR syntax. For example, the `^` does not negate characters in ANTLR. Also, you're trying to handle just a very small subset of how a char set might look like in a single token, which is really not the way to go. It's nice of you that you try to help people, but your comments are (IMO) more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to handle this in the parser, not the lexer.  When lexer sees a '(', it will return token LBrace.  For lexer, there is no context as to where token is seen.  It simply carves up the input into tokens.  You will have to define parse rules and when processing parse tree, you can then determine was the LBrace inside brackets or not.

Comment: I am trying to get this the whole day :-)
If i try this example `[0-9]{3}-(([0-9()+\-]|G{1})|([A-Z]{2}))`  I get this tree (braces in lower left) [link](http://z62i.imgup.net/tree520b.png)
What i would like is to see them as is exactChar.alphNum.
But if I just add the braces to alphnum or some new token, it messes with the whole group thing. Every brace gets to be an exact character.

Comment: Yes, you can handle it in the parser, but with ANTLR4, modes can also be used to give the lexer some context sensitivity.

Comment: @user1941235, you may have your answer by using parser rules only (which is a perfectly fine solution). But for completeness sake, I also added an answer that shows how to do it using lexical modes. Best of luck!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick demo of how it is possible to create a context sensitive lexer using ANTLR4's lexical-modes:

```
lexer grammar RegexLexer;

START_CHAR_CLASS
 : '[' -> pushMode(CharClass)
 ;

START_GROUP
 : '('
 ;

END_GROUP
 : ')'
 ;

PLAIN_ATOM
 : ~[()\[\]]
 ;

mode CharClass;

END_CHAR_CLASS
 : ']' -> popMode
 ;

CHAR_CLASS_ATOM
 : ~[\r\n\\\]]
 | '\\' .
 ;
```

After generating the lexer, you can use the following class to test it:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RegexLexer lexer = new RegexLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("([()\\]])"));
        for (Token token : lexer.getAllTokens()) {
            System.out.printf("%-20s %s\n", RegexLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(token.getType()), token.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

And if you run this Main class, the follwoing will be printed to your console:

```
START_GROUP          (
START_CHAR_CLASS     [
CHAR_CLASS_ATOM      (
CHAR_CLASS_ATOM      )
CHAR_CLASS_ATOM      \]
END_CHAR_CLASS       ]
END_GROUP            )
```

As you can see, the `(` and `)` are tokenized differently outside the character class as they are inside of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for that example. I think I am good with the parser solution, but I will most certainly try out the lexer modes!
At this moment the focus is to get some C# code working with this basic grammar I have built. And for now I have no idea how to approach it :-)

Comment: No problem. You may also want to have a look at this PCRE grammar: https://github.com/bkiers/pcre-parser/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/nl/bigo/pcreparser/PCRE.g4