# how to match a sequence that has no separation with whitespace

Tags: antlr4

The rule I am trying to match is: `hello` followed by a sequence of characters. If that sequence contains an alphabet in it, that should match the `str` rule, else it should match the `num` rule.

For e.g.

`hello123` - 123 should be matched by num rule

`hello1a3` - 1a3 should be matched by the str rule

The grammar I wrote is below:

```
grammar Hello;

r: 'hello'seq;
// seq: str | integ;
seq: num | str;
num : DIGITS;
str : CHARS;
DIGITS: [0-9]+;
CHARS : [0-9a-zA-Z]+;
WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

While trying to visualize the parse tree (using grun) (against the first input example above) I got the below parse tree:

[image]

However if the input had space in between there was no problem. Please explain why the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexing in ANTLR (as well as most lexer generators) works according to the maximum munch rule, which says that it always applies the lexer rule that could match the longest prefix of the current input. For the input `hello123`, the rule `'hello'` would match `hello`, whereas the rule `CHARS` would match the entire input `hello123`. Therefore `CHARS` produces the longer match and is chosen over `'hello'`.

If your `CHARS` and `DIGITS` tokens can only appear after a `'hello'` token, you can use [lexer modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes) to make it so that these rules are only available after a `'hello'` has been matched.

Otherwise, to get the behaviour you want, your best bet would probably be to create a single lexer rule that matches `'hello' [0-9a-zA-Z]*` and then take apart the tokens generated by that in a separate step. Though it all depends on why you need this.

Comment: I am used to another parser generator software before antlr - so hacking my way trying to understand how to use the tool. Are there any examples in the antlr repo that use these lexer modes?

Comment: @deostroll click on the link to the documentation. There are examples there (especially the 'Tokenizing XML' part). Also, here's an example on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229658/antlr4-regex-lexer-modes HTH